# What what be the best pattern of layers for my Tensorflow/Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently making an Airbus/Boeing classifier that can determine what aircraft the image is of. I have resized my images to be 1000 by 1000. Do any of you guys mind giving me an example f how I should go about constructing a model with Tensorflow and Keras? Also, what types of layers should I include? I am new to Tensorflow so I am not aware of the types of layers I should use for the maximum accuracy. Thank you. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

boeing_dir = '#'
airbus_dir = '#'
path = '#'



boeing_data = []
boeing_label = []
airbus_data = []
airbus_label = []
print('begun')
for filename in os.listdir(boeing_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        path_b = os.path.join(boeing_dir, filename)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (1000, 1000))
        boeing_data.append(im)
        boeing_label.append(0)
        print(im.shape)

for filename in os.listdir(airbus_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        path_b = os.path.join(airbus_dir, filename)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (1000, 1000))
        airbus_data.append(im)
        airbus_label.append(1)
        print(im.shape)



training_data = boeing_data + airbus_data
training_label = boeing_label + airbus_label
print(training_data)
print(training_label)
training_data = np.array(training_data)#.reshape(-1, 1000, 1000, 1)
training_label = np.asarray(training_label)
```

I have split the images into images and labels. After this, how do I construct my model?

Comment: You probably can't fit all those images in memory, you should use  [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)  instead

Answer (score 0):

You should probably experiment first with a prebuilt model. You should do some research before building your own model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201 as b # 
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers, regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

The applications module offers a lot more models to choose from.

```
traingen =image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validationgen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
testgen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train = traingen.flow_from_directory("train",target_size=(1000, 1000), batch_size=batchSize, shuffle=True)
val = validationgen.flow_from_directory("validation",target_size=(1000, 1000), batch_size=size, shuffle=False)
test=testgen.flow_from_directory("test",target_size=(1000, 1000), batch_size=size, shuffle=False)
```

For this you should split your data in three folders, one for train, validation and test data. inside of these folders you should have two more folders called "boeing" and "airbus" that yontain those respective images. This code reads the images from tose three folders and inferes the class from the folder names

```
 base = b(include_top=False, # include top refers if to include the dense layer that acts as the classifier, this is not needed in this case because we build one later
            weights="imagenet", # these are the weights used by the model that were learned from being trained on the imagenet dataset
            input_shape=(1000, 1000, 3)) # in case you work with rgb images, if you work with gray images you should use input_shape=(1000, 1000, 1)

x = base.output
predictions = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), 
          loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
          metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])


history = model.fit_generator(train,
                          steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(numImages/batchSize),
                          epochs=50,
                          verbose=2,
                          validation_data= val,
                          validation_steps=np.ceil(nunImages/size)
                          )
```

By using a pretrained network you can take advantage of the knowledge learned from imagenet, those patterns shoud be useful since you are working with natural images.